# How can i test my application directly on device

Tags: ios

I have already an apple id. I try to get the provisioning profile. However, it seems that i need to purchase a program, is there any other free possibility or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple ID is only the first Part of it. You need the iOS Developer Programm. With this program you get access to all the things you need to get your application on a device. (Certificate and provisioning files)

The otherway is to jailbreak your device and add it with SSH to your device. But I don't exactely know how to do that. There are several tutorials on the internet. ;-)

Sandro Meier